# Defunct as of rlang 0.3.0 and mutate_impl

Tags: r, rlang

I am trying to use the following function but every time I do, I receive the error below. I tried installing an older version of rlang as it works on a different R Studio but I was unable to do that. It seems the error is due to the 0.3.0 version. Any suggestions on how to fix this error would be appreciated.

```
details2 <-
   details %>%
   mutate(rownames=rownames(.)) %>%
   filter(isdir==FALSE) %>%
   arrange(desc(ctime))

Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Evaluation error: `as_dictionary()` is defunct as of rlang 0.3.0.
Please use `as_data_pronoun()` instead.
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To solve this issue within a docker container, I ended up having to use `devtools::install_version(..., dep = FALSE)` to install an older version of `rlang` and manually install all dependencies for the packages I needed like `dplyr`.

Simply installing `dplyr` will install (or update) to the most recent version of `rlang` which released `0.3.0` on `2018-10-22` according to CRAN. Although I haven't figured out what changed with `rlang` and `as_dictionary`, this is a current workaround.

Although this was a pain, it did work. 
To find all imports for a particular package you can use `as.data.frame(installed.packages())` and filter for the specific package name you are interested in. The column name is `Imports`.

Edit:
Although I have not tested it myself, another solution I found online is to upgrade dplyr to `0.7.7`.

Comment: I did not understand how to use your solution. I updated tidyverse Today and everything became a complete mess in my code :(

Comment: I have the same problem :( which version of rlang did you use? thanks!

Comment: I ended up using version `0.1.6` and didn't have any issues
Additional documentation on the `0.3.0` update can be found here https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rlang/news/news.html

Answer (score 4):

I think the problem may come from incompatible package versions. You can try with:

```
update.packages(ask = FALSE, checkBuilt = TRUE)
```

If it doesn't work, reinstalling all packages the problem may disappear (code from [here](https://www.r-bloggers.com/automated-re-install-of-packages-for-r-3-0/)):

```
package_df <- as.data.frame(installed.packages())
package_list <- as.character(package_df$Package)
install.packages(package_list)
```

Comment: Have you tried working with this solution? It appears not to e working on my side

Comment: This worked on my computer.  It took awhile because of the number of packages I have.

Comment: @ConfusionMatrix it worked in my case. The fact is that reinstalling all packages the incompatibilities between package versions were fixed. That was the reason in my case.

Comment: @garciparedes it worked but I did something else in addition to what you suggested. I had to manually update some packages to avoid conflicts.

Answer (score 2):

Problem happened after installing new version of **RStudio-1.2.1114.exe**

To solve this problem I just had to install package 'dplyr' again

```
install.packages("dplyr")
```

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me (though to be honest I don't fully understand why):

1) Delete the rlang folder from the computer (on Windows: R/win-library/3.4)
2) `install.packages("dplyr")`

In the two cases where I encountered this problem, the system was operating on R 3.4 with Windows. It's possible that the R3.4/Windows had something to do with it.

Comment: On ubuntu 16, R. 3.4.4.  Just updating dplyr with `install.packages("dplyr")` fixed it for me.  I did _not_ delete the rlang folder.

Comment: I do not have a "win-lib" folder in my R folder... anywhere else it might be?

Comment: It's actually win-library (sorry about the mistake).  I'll update my original response to reflect that.  You can check where your packages are installed by running `path.package("PKG_NAME")`

Answer (score 0):

I temporarily solved the problem via downgrading rlang.

```
require(devtools)
install_version("rlang", version = "x.x.x", repos = "http://cran.us.r-project.org")
```

x.x.x: the version you need

---

I just realize that "dplyr" has fixed the issue after version 0.7.4.

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, it worked for me by doing this:

1. having dplyr version 0.7.8
2. having rlang version 0.3.0.9000

I have R version 3.4.3 and using Rstudio version 1.1.456.

Answer (score -3):

Try the following command: 
This will bring rlang to version 0.2.1

Post this you will be able to run the command.